# turn on mysql profiler globally

Tags: mysql, profiling

I want to profile all mysql sessions using mysql profiler, how can I turn on profiling globally?

thanks!

Comment: What aspects of "profiling" are you looking for?  There may be a way to get what you desire, but by using some other technique.

Comment: @RickJames, my assumption is that the OP meant profiling as in [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/show-profile.html)

Comment: (I find the output of Profile being next-to-useless.)

Comment: @RickJames please could you explain why that is?

Comment: @gen - In my opinion, Profile was was not well designed for the end-user.  It monitors a lot of low-level actions, but not the tasks in evaluating the query.  Run it on a variety of queries that take more than a second.  Take not of the largest item in the list, and how big the percentage is.

Comment: @gen - When the query has both `GROUP BY` and a _different_ `ORDER BY`, there will _probably_ be 2 sorts.  `EXPLAIN` and `PROFILE` fail to point this out.  (`EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON` does.)

Comment: @gen - See also "Optimizer Trace".

Comment: Thanks, @RickJames

Answer (score 3):

I think you can run these commands to enable profiling:

```
SET GLOBAL slow_query_log = 'ON';
SET GLOBAL slow_query_log_file = '/var/log/mysql/localhost-slow.log';
SET GLOBAL log_queries_not_using_indexes = 'ON';
SET SESSION long_query_time = 1;
SET SESSION min_examined_row_limit = 100;
```

The settings will not persist after you reboot the server - if you want these enabled upon the next server restart, you can add them to your `my.cnf` configuration file:

```
[mysqld]
slow-query-log = 1
slow-query-log-file = /var/log/mysql/localhost-slow.log
long_query_time = 1
log-queries-not-using-indexes
```

Info from [this page](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-mysql-query-profiling).